# Using Freemarker to generate Java .properties files

Tags: java, freemarker, properties-file

I am currently using Freemarker to generate a number of configuration files. So far these have been either xml files or properietary format text files. I now would like to generate some Java .properties files but have hit a couple of issues.

The first is character encoding. As far as I can see simply adding

```
<#ftl encoding="8859_1">
```

to the start of the file should sort this out.

The second issue is the escaping of the keys and values. The keys are probably ok as I would be hardcoding these in the template anyway so I can escape them in the template. The values will be coming from my data model and so will need escaping.

I can see how I can create my own [user defined directive](http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/docs/pgui_datamodel_directive.html) and by installing it as a [shared variable](http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/docs/pgui_config_sharedvariables.html) use it in my template.

Is this the best or only way to do this? I would have thought generating .properties files is something that has been tackled many times before and was hoping something may already exist before I start writing my own code.

Comment: Regarding that charset name, maybe Java recognizes `8859_1` (I don't know), but it should be `ISO-8859-1`.

Answer (score 2):

The class java.util.Properties got various store methods to save properties to OutputStreams or files. This seems more preferable than trying to adapt freemarker.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get what are the charset issues that are specific to generating `properties` files. But note that the charset of the template and the charset of the output are independent, so you might as well use the same charset for these templates as for the others (like maybe UTF-8).

As of escaping, always use auto-escaping if you can. In 2.3.24 that will be especially sleek, but unless you are allowed to use unreleased versions, you had to wait for that until the end of February or so. (If you can use unreleased/unofficial versions, [you can find](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-freemarker-dev/201601.mbox/%3C1577635506.20160107222932%40freemail.hu%3E) out about the internal testing releases in the developer list archive.) Before 2.3.24, there's `<#escape x as propEsc(x)>all the template content here</#escape>`, where `propEsc` is a `TemplateMethodModelEx` (not a `TemplateDirectiveModel`) that you have added as shared variable or such. And so all `${...}`-s will be magically escaped.

Comment: There isn't particularly an issue with charsets - its just that Java .properties files always use 8859_1. In my case I have a number of files being templated at the same time using a common data model, all are UTF-8 except for the .properties files. I am doing a bulk operation, iterating over all the templates and processing each in turn - I don't want to have any special cases. It seems adding the encode directive in the template addresses this.

Comment: Adding an `#ftl encoding` only addresses this if you also ensure that the result `OutputStreamWriter` uses ISO-8859-1. One idea for that is using the return value of `template.getEncoding()` to set the output charset. (BTW, it's again 2.3.24 only, but there you can configure FreeMarker so that all `*.properties.ftl` templates use ISO-8859-1, and the others use UTF-8. Thus you will be able to get rid if the `#ftl` headers. Similarly you will be able to specify the escaping algorithm used based on template name patterns.)

Comment: I have set the output encoding to match the input encoding of the .properties template, which is (now) set to ISO_8859_1, and it all seems to be working fine. I look forward to 2.3.24! I suspect .properties files are always going to be awkward as it seems they don't use a "file wide" escaping algorithm - they have a slightly different escaping algorithm for the keys and values.

Comment: Though keys usually don't contain arbitrary characters. But yes, in general the template can't know that. One thing you could do is having property-value escaping by default, and then add explicit escaping to keys. Something like `${escKey(key)} = ${value}`. With the 2.3.24 escaping mechanism, the `escKey` function can indicate in its return value that it's already escaped, and thus you don't end up with double escaping.

Comment: Note that the charset name is still not canonical in your comment, as you are using `_` instead of `-`.

Comment: That's two mistakes in one 10 character string! I also think that if somebody is templating .properties files it is likely they wil have fixed keys and template the values (which is what I am doing) so the file level escaping policy is likely to be ok.